# Why is only a small piece of this div visible?

Tags: javascript, css, html, visibility

I am running a test javascript/CSS app and there is a div that is exhibiting very strange behavior. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

Point your browsers at http://korhal.andrewmao.net:9294/, and check out the `div.payment` (`div` with class `payment`) in the DOM.

This div contains an image and some text, but none of it's visible except for a tiny end piece of the text which shows up on Chrome and FF but not IE9. I haven't styled this part of the DOM yet but I can't even figure out why it is completely invisible. Examining the applied CSS doesn't seem to turn up any z-index, transparency, or hidden issues. Any suggestions?

My apologies, this code is hard to gist and this link may be subject to change.

Comment: Add `position: relative` to your `payment` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ur `.background` is position fixed it will come on top , so u have to add
 `position:relative` to  `div.payment`

Comment: That's very interesting...I never knew about this. Why does a div with `position:fixed` display on top of another div without `position:relative`?

Comment: worth reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index .. its bit tricky :)

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
.payment img {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and

```
.payment p {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image]